# How to create image scrolling in Wordpress like the NYT website?

Tags: wordpress, animation, scroll

I am new to Wordpress, I was trying to clone some website such as the new york times.
I do not know how to implement the same effect on their website when one scrolls down.
Basically while scrolling down the website loads 3 pictures.
How can I achieve that effect, can someone suggest me some free plugin or something like that ?
I already tried with scrollsequence but it does not work